# Text does not appear on UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Pounding my head against this. Should be so simple.

Running in a playground inside `MyClass:`

```
func configureButton(){
    let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(5, 75, 90, 20))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    btn.addTarget(self,
                  action: #selector(MyClass.buttonTapped),
                  forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    addSubview(btn)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 40)
    btn.titleLabel?.text = "tap me"
  }
```

The button shows up green, and works when pressed, but does not display the text.

Comment: Is this even your real code? This line makes no sense: `uiView().addSubview(btn)`

Comment: It is my real code, and it works, but I can see how that line is confusing. I'll edit it for clarity.

Comment: But you see, you are still not answering the key questions, such as where this code occurs and what view you are adding the button as a subview of.

Comment: Not really key questions, though, since the answer below solved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is just wrong:

```
btn.titleLabel?.text = "tap me"
```

Do not attempt to manipulate the button's title label text directly like this. Always pass through the button's official title setter, `setTitle:forState:`.